# what are all the locations in which connectionStrings can be defined for an iis site?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, connection-string

I'm trying to find all the locations in which a connectionString can be defined for an iis site (to write a script to extract them all).
I know it can be part of a web.config. I would like to have a complete list of files it can be configured in.
Does it make sense for it to be configured in the site code?
Which other configuration files can define a site's connectionStrings?

And a bonus question - how do I know the order of the files in which the connectionString is searched in ?

Thanks,

EDIT:
Additional info - all IIS sites are pure dotnet sites.

Also, specifying the general location of files, rather then file names, is also helpful. 
E.g. - connectionStings can be located in external configuration files, whose location is defined at a in an [appSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/appsettings/) element in the  "%runtime install path%\config\machine.config" file.

Another option is to just link to the relevant docs. 
My issue is that I haven't found anything conclusive.

Comment: So you are doing blindly guesses. Different web stacks use different files/approaches to store connection strings, and `web.config` isn't the only (probably not even the most common) place. If you don't edit the question to give more details on the context, it is impossible to discuss further.

Comment: I thought IIS was a web stack. Which additional information could I give you? How do pure dotnet iis sites further diverge ?

Comment: There is no "dotnet", but either .NET Framework or .NET Core at this very moment. So you have to be more specific in order to make the discussion meaningful. The answer below shows some hints on .NET Framework web apps.

Comment: I mean dotnet Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty good source for the locations of the IIS dotnet Framework configuration files - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754617(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#inheritance

You could define additional connectionStrings

1. In dotnet code.
2. In env.
3. In external config files.
4. For non-IIS scopes - such as user scopes and role scopes.

These 4 options are not specific to IIS.
I don't know where options (3) and (4) are defined, and I'm not sure if this list is complete. But by combing this list and the one in the doc, I think we have 99% coverage of defined connectionStrings.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are several ways to configure connectionstring in ASP.NET applications.

1. Define it in code. This is the method used by many beginners. Because at this time they focus on code learning and logical understanding. But some people are accustomed to using it if the database is fixed, it does not need to be modified.

   ```
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mytest;Integrated Security=True");
   ```
2. Define it in web.config or App.config. The benefit of it is easy to modified connectionstring after publishing application. Developers can change web.config, no need to change code and deploy application again.

   ```
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="mytest" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mytest;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
    </connectionStrings>
   ```
3. Using [External Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#using-external-configuration-files). ConnectionString is stored in a independent file for example connections.config. The benefit of it is modifying an external configuration file does not cause an application restart.

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>  
   <configuration>  
     <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>  
   </configuration>
   ```

About list all connectionstrings, you can use  [ConnectionStringSettingsCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#retrieving-connection-strings-at-run-time). It can get a connection by name and provider name.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, my script is running by mounting the disks of offline VMs, so I can only read the file-system, and wouldn't have access to runtime information.  Also, the link you provided doens't describe the full list of files \ locations where the connectionString can be defined in. For example applicationhost.config isn't mentioned, but global connecitonStrings can be defined there.

Comment: @NimrodFiat mounting disks raises the bar significantly for your analysis, as you run out of the scope of existing IIS/ASP.NET management API/scripts and have to roll out your own analysis logic. That is doable for very experienced IIS professionals, but again requires far more hours than typing just a few paragraphs as an answer.

Comment: OK, then I'll accept this answer for lack for a better alternative. I don't think there is a lot of analysis logic to do (assuming I'm willing to ignore fully encrypted sections of the config). Maybe I'll upload an answer if I ever find a complete list of iis config files. Thanks again.